# Layout overlapping issue with dynamically created items in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have created a Relative Layout with 3 layouts inside. 
first Linear layout with dynamically added textView
second Table Layout with dynamically created table
third Linear Layout with dyanmically created href (web links)

but these three layouts are overlapping, here is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutHome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TableLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutWSMethods"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried changing RelativeLayout with FrameLayout but its overlapping too.

Comment: You could change the RelativeLayout (root) for a LinearLayout and assign the same weight to all its children (LinearLayout, TableLayout and LinearLayout).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to fix this you need to use properties of the RelativeLayout. For example if you wanted to align them all beneath each other and aligned on the right side your code would look like the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutHome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/layoutHome">
    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutWSMethods"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/table_main">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The properties `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and `android:layout_below="@id/layoutID"` are just two. A good place to start would be here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Comment: I have change alighParentRight to Left and its working Thanks @Pete Za

Comment: The left top corner is default for view alignment. And for your simple layout you should use LinearLayout, while RelativeLayout measures twice before drawing.

Comment: @ThomasR. Yes, you are correct on both accounts. I didn't want to assume that the OP wanted a linear design. The problem only mentions that the layouts are overlapping. With a relative layout the children can be placed to the left/right, above/below, etc. which would solve the overlapping but wouldn't necessarily be linear

Answer (score 1):

Use a Linearlayout with either vertical or horizontal orientation.

A Framelayout is intended to overlap the views in the order you add them.

For a RelativeLayout it is the same if you do not arrange your views like below or above a specific view. As the name states, your arrange them in a relative manner.

Comment: thanks @Thomar R. that's working now with replacing Relative Layout with Linear Layout . How can I add a new line like thing in between layouts using xml? That will be great help. Thanks again

Comment: I have used android:layout_marginBottom="10dp", for new line like thing between layouts andit  is working.